# Reset and restart pygame program doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame

I have an issue with resetting my game in pygame when the user is asked to restart. The program is constructed like this:

```
import board as b

class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.gamestate = b.GameState()

    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        running = False
                        pygame.quit()
                        Gui().run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui().run()
```

What happens when the user tries to restart is that the Gui closes and the while loop exits as they should. It then opens a new window BUT it has not cleared the gamestate, so my gamestate from previous run is still there. I thought that the line `self.gamestate = b.GameState()` would create a new gamestate for me but that seems not to be the case. Here is a short snippet from the board file:

```
class GameState:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = s.start_position
```

When calling it I thought it would set the board to start position and all its parameters to inititial, but something is not right and I have not been able to solve this for 3 days now. I hope you can help me how to clear the gamestate and start from fresh again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overcomplicated the system. What you are actually doing is recursively instantiating a new `Gui` object and new application loop into an existing `Gui` object and application loop.
If `GameState` is implemented correctly, it should be sufficient to create a new `GameState` object and continue the existing application loop instead of recursively creating a new `Gui` instance:

```py
import board as b

class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.gamestate = b.GameState()

    def run(self):

        running = True
        while running:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    pygame.quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        self.gamestate = b.GameState()

            # [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui().run()
```

---

The instruction `self.board = s.start_position` doesn't create a new board object. `self.board` and `s.start_position` refer to the same object. If you change one of the objects, the other object seems to change in the same way since there is only one object.
Either you need to make a deep copy of the board object when you start the game or you need to reset the object when the game restarts.

A solution might be to use the Python [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module. `deepcopy` can create a deep copy of an object:

```py
import copy
```

```py
self.board = copy.deepcopy(s.start_position)`
```

Note, not all object can be *deep* copied. For instance a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) cannot be *deep* copied.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case unfortunately. I even tried to put self.gamestate = b.GameState() and  self.gamestate.board = s.start_board under the keypress but the board is still unaffected. I do also init some parameters in the Gui which would need to be reset.

Comment: @eligolf Anyway, your recursive approach can cause side effects. If my approach doesn't work, if you've messed up something in your application.

Comment: I will look at it again, but my current 3 days of debugging has not led me anywhere :( Everything is resetting (move log, player turn etc). Only the board isn't updating properly even if I explicitly tells it to.

Comment: It seems as if declaring the self.board = s.start_board alters with my original s.start_board. So when I reset it actually works, but the original values has changed. Do you have any idea how to fix this. Your solution is good and I accept it as an answer, this is some other issue.

Comment: @eligolf I've extended the answer.